# Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'ArgentineWine' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1442

I have read the 4 cases in this forum reg.

> Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'tablename' in stored  function/trigger because it is already used by statement

Those cases are way more complex than my situation. I created an `ArgentineWines` table with 5 columns, loaded 10 rows, and created a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_Before_An_ArgentineWines_update 
AFTER UPDATE ON ArgentineWines
FOR EACH ROW 
    INSERT INTO ArgentineWines
    SET action = 'update',
        RankingId = OLD.RankingId,
        WineName = OLD.WineName,
        Description = OLD.Description,
        RecordDate = NOW();
```

The problem arises when I try to test out the trigger by making a change to the table. I attempted to update the table in two different ways

First attempt:

```
USE Sakila;

UPDATE ArgentineWines
SET WineName = REPLACE(WineName,'GRAFFIGNA RESERVE','GRAFFIGNA RESERVE Grandiose')
WHERE RankingId = 6;
```

Second attempt:

```
USE Sakila;

UPDATE ArgentineWines
SET WineName = 'GRAFFIGNA RESERVE Grandiose'
WHERE RankingId = 6;
```

No matter what I try, I get this error:

> Error Code: 1442. Can't update table '**argentinewines**' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

I have used BEFORE I have used AFTER, no matter what the error keeps popping up.

**Questions**: which other statement is invoking my stored procedure? What is already using what? The error description is not that clear.

Please, any thoughts or a solution to this mystery will be great. DH

Comment: You must not insert new rows for table A inside an update trigger on that same table A

Comment: Thank you for the reply Michael. I am a newbie and got "inspired" to create my sample code from this example mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx . It seems it may worked by inserting into the same table. Per your reply, would it be possible to insert into a different table i.e. INSERT INTO ArgentineWines2 ?. Or is there any other way to correct/fix something inside the code I presented.  I tried to make a link for the URL but it did not work, sorry.  I am stuck at this stage in my learning tutorial, stuck for about a week. Your feedback will be highly appreciated.  D.H